# How to connect IntelliJ IDEA / WebStorm with Docker Desktop

Tags: reactjs, docker, intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm using Docker for Desktop on Mac for my React app and WebStorm.

The containers are running and I've added it in WebStorm Preferences/Build/Docker as you can see on the photo.

[image]

Everything works fine, but the problem is that WebStorm autocomplete and auto import do not work. And also all imports are shown as warnings (Module not found)

[image]

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `node_modules` installed remotely, in a container? This setup is not currently supported, please follow [WEB-55591](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-55591/Remote-Docker-nodemodules-not-detected) for updates to get notified on any progress with this feature